# Google plus signin with multiple Google users signed in

Tags: javascript, google-plus

Scenario:

1. User signs in with Google Plus button on Page 1.
2. The app creates a session and renders Page 2, which has a hidden G+ signin button.
3. The app waits for the signin callback to be fired before accessing some Google resources.

This works fine if the user is only signed-in to one Google account, but if the user is signed in to more than one account, the callback is fired with 'immediate_failed' error, meaning that the user needs to press the button again. I don't want the user to have to sign-in again, or run the risk that he uses two different accounts for the two sign-ins.

Is there a way to persist the Google user chosen in step 1 to step 3?

Comment: That should work - my guess is that the cookiepolicy you're using is overly restricted, so the cookie which indicates the selected user is not available from page1 to page2.

If that's not it, could you post a running bit of code somewhere as an example?

Comment: @Ian Barber Thanks. It's working now. Not sure what happened :(.

Comment: Hi, I have the same problem, but can't find how to fix it...